# How to click second href text in different div using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I tried to click a text using selenium.
here is what the html looks like.

```
<div id="boxTimeHistory">
<div class="tableB selectTop pt0">
<div class="tab">..</div>
<div class="box_contents">
    <div>
       <table>..</table>
       <div class="paging">
                <strong>1</strong>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">2</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">3</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">4</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">5</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">6</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">7</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">8</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">9</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">10</a>          
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btnNext" title="다음">다음</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btnLast" title="마지막">마지막</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
....
....
....
<div id="boxDayHistory">
<div class="tableB selectTop pt0">
<div class="tab">..</div>
<div class="box_contents">
    <div>
       <table>..</table>
       <div class="paging">
                <strong>1</strong>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">2</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">3</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">4</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">5</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">6</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">7</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">8</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">9</a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnMove">10</a>          
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btnNext" title="다음">다음</a>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btnLast" title="마지막">마지막</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I only want to click second href text from the **boxDayHistory** section and 
not above one.

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("2").click()
```

but, it clicked the first one, div id = "boxTimdHistory"

also I tired,

```
links = driver.find_element_by_link_text("2")
for link in links:
   link.click()
```

and this one gave me error..

help me plz thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click the element with text as **2** from **boxDayHistory** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#boxDayHistory div.paging a:first-child"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='boxDayHistory']//a[@class='btnMove' and text()='2']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_element_by_link_text("2")` finds the **first** link with the given text. Thats the link inside `boxTimeHistory`.

Try

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#boxDayHistory .btnMove").click()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get link with text 2 under Day History by using xpath below:

```
dayLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="boxDayHistory"]//a[.= "2"]')
```